# R: Implement name matching using bipartite graph

Tags: r, igraph, bipartite

I'm trying to do name matching using bipartite graph theory. Ideally I'd like to be able to return the percent match at the end. So here is an example:

```
v1 = "John Alex Smith"
v2 = "John A Smith"
```

I want to be able to produce a graph like this:

```
"J" "O" "H" "N" "A" "L" "E" "X" "S" "M" "I" "T" "H"
 |   |   |   |   |               |   |   |   |   |
"J" "O" "H" "N" "A"             "S" "M" "I" "T" "H"
```

I have some code I've written based on a few examples I've found online. `vert1` and `vert2`are character vectors.

```
edgeVec <- c(vert1, vert2)
g <- make_empty_graph(n=0, directed = FALSE)
g <- add.vertices(g, nv=length(vert1), attr=list(name=paste0(vert1), 
                  type=rep(TRUE, length(vert1))))
g <- add.vertices(g, nv=length(vert2), attr=list(name=vert2), 
                  type=rep(FALSE, length(vert2)))

g <- add.edges(g, edgeVec)

plot.igraph(g, layout=layout.bipartite, vertex.color=c("blue", "green")[V(g)$type+1])
is.bipartite(g)
```

Right now it is plotting the vertices (very closely together to the point where you can't tell which letter goes with which circle), 'however, it is not plotting edges connecting the vertices'.

So I have 2 questions,

> how do I make the vertices graphically more separated?
>
> how do I compose my edge vector?

Right now I'm combining both `vert1` and `vert2` into "edgeVec", which is probably not the best way to do it and probably also my problem.